# Android PhoneStateListener runs on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, phone-state-listener

I've tried to build a piece of code that "verifies" data connectivity;
Say the user has turned data on, I'd like to "wait" for it to come back, up to a limit of time:

```
final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        // occurs also when network state changes
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

I register the listener:

```
telMgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
```

then I wait on the lock:

```
synchronized (lock) {
            if (telMgr.getDataState() != TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED)
                lock.wait(timeMS);
        }
```

It seems to always wait the whole `timeMS` ms, even if I turn data on pretty long before. When debugging, it seems that only after the wait ends, and the activity flow continues, I get notified about the "OnDataConnectionState" change only later, several times, as if the listener is running on the same main thread, and once the main thread blocks, no "events" are received and the "OnDataStateChange" method is not invoked.
How indeed does the listener work, and is it possible to work this out some way?

Full code of the meth

```
public static boolean verifyDataConnectivity(long timeMS, Context context)
{
    final Object lock= new Object();
    final Context mainContext = context;
    final TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)(mainContext
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
   // Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   // Handler handler = new Handler( mainContext.getMainLooper());
    final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        // occurs also when network state changes
        @Override
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    try {

        telMgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);

        Runnable rListener = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Register phone state listener:
                telMgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);

            }
        };

       // handler.post(rListener);

        synchronized (lock) {
            if (telMgr.getDataState() != TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED)
                lock.wait(timeMS);
        }
        if (telMgr.getDataState() != TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED)
            return false;

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(ANDROID_COMMON_TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (phoneStateListener != null)
            telMgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can show us, where you define `lock` ? I suspect you are waiting on the wrong object.

Comment: The lock is defined in the beginning of the method. method is static:
`public static boolean verifyDataConnectivity(long timeMS, Context context) {
final Object lock = new Object();`
The reason it's final is cause I've also tried using a handler and a different thread to do that, it did not work as well

Comment: Could you please add all `verifyDataConnectivity` code to your question? Still suspecting some issue with the lock object.

Comment: I have added the complete code. thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run it in a worker thread looper?